# Emoji features used in the sentiment analysis are not showing on my LIME figures

Tags: sentiment-analysis, text-classification, lime, bilstm, xai

I'm a student from a business school, and trying to learn how to use advanced data analytics.

My model uses Bilstm to conduct a sentiment classification task. The dataset consists of 80000 tweets. The features includes words and emojis. I'm trying to apply LIME and get some figures that can show EMOJI AND WORD features.

Thanks to https://data4thought.com/deep-lime.html#deep-lime.  I succeesfully applied LIME to the model. But the resulting figures didn't show the emoji features, only the word features. I don't know what's going wrong and how to fix it. Could you help me with this issue?

The code is here[text](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DiU0gKOUXnfBYgW5u0LQEO21TqgOSpTN?usp=sharing)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxggo.png)